# Trace file oracle. How match name 'SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6616_3CFB8B'(or Object Id = -40016362) with specific materialize block (with as)

Tags: oracle, etl, trace

I started learning Oracle query optimization. And I have a question about the trace file.

There is a query plan in the trace file, for example (Sorry that without formatting, you don’t have to read it, just pay attention to `SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6611_3CFB8B`):

```
    TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION  (cr=4,525,645 pr=1 pw=1 time=6.1696s)
      LOAD AS SELECT  (cr=2 pr=0 pw=1 time=0.0006s)
        TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE3 (cr=2 pr=0 pw=0 time=0.0000s cost=2 size=12 card=4)
      SORT AGGREGATE (cr=4,525,643 pr=1 pw=0 time=6.1689s)
        NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=4,525,643 pr=1 pw=0 time=6.8775s cost=4,522,314 size=42,943,800 card=2,260,200)
          TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE1 (cr=5,241 pr=0 pw=0 time=0.6861s cost=1,429 size=13,561,200 card=2,260,200)
          VIEW  (cr=4,520,402 pr=1 pw=0 time=5.2771s cost=2 size=13 card=1)
            TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6616_3CFB8B (cr=4,520,402 pr=1 pw=0 time=4.1430s cost=2 size=12 card=4)
```

When the request has a materialized block, for example:

```
    with tmp as 
    (select /*+ materialize */ * from table t
    where t.val = 'A')
```

Then in the trace file in the query plan, the following lines appear:

```
    STAT #398394272 id=12 cnt=4 pid=11 pos=1 obj=-40016367 op='TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6611_3CFB8B (cr=4 pr=1 pw=0 time=324 us cost=2 size=12 card=4)'
```

When the materialized block in the request only one, it is easy to understand that it refers specifically to the above `with` block.

But when there are a lot of blocks `with`, it is not clear from the trace file which block the `object SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6611_3CFB8B` belongs to.

I tried to match by name `object SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6611_3CFB8B` and object number `obj=-40016367`, but from the file it’s still not clear what’s what.

Can you tell me how to determine which material block a pronoun refers to?

In the queries that I deal with at work, there are 10-40 of these material blocks. Because of this, it is very easy to get confused in plan of request.

Or maybe I'm generally doing something wrong? My ultimate goal is to understand where the requests in the ETL process hang. If I try to analyze something wrong, advise how best to do it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `MATERIALIZE` hint?

Comment: If i remove the ``MATERIALIZE`` hint, then materialization will not happen and oracle will convert the query to a standard table join. And then according to the request plan it will be clear what exactly is happening.

If you want to suggest using this option for debugging, then this will not work. Because when I remove the hint, the query plan will not be equivalent to the original plan, which is executed in production. And I can not find the cause of the hang.

Comment: Sorry, I misphrased that. What is the performance of your query like without the `MATERIALIZE` hint?

Comment: The query performance from the example was normal. Hash join is also used there as in the case with ``MATERIALIZE`` hint. But at work in large requests with 20-40 blocks ``with``, performance without a hint is deteriorating. Oracle tries to join tables in a bad sequence, ``nested loops`` and ``merge join cartesian`` also appear

Comment: If you have diagnostics and tuning pack license, you can get to the bottleneck pretty quickly by running the SQL through the SQL Tuning Advisor.  The only way I know of to understand which temp table applies to which sub-query is to check the join order where it is used and with that information deduce which subquery the temp table came from.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan is normally a good indicator here. The LOAD AS SELECT will show you the phase at which the temp table is created, and then the access of the temp table will appear later in the plan. By looking at the operations "under" the LOAD AS SELECT, you hopefully can tie this back to the SQL text in the query

```
SQL> create table t as select * from dba_Objects;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> with
  2  t1 as
  3  ( select /*+ materialize */ owner, count(*) c1
  4    from   t
  5    group by owner ),
  6  t2 as
  7  ( select /*+ materialize */ owner, max(object_id) c2
  8    from   t
  9    group by owner ),
 10  t3 as
 11  ( select /*+ materialize */ t1.owner, c1,c2
 12    from   t1,t2
 13    where t1.owner = t2.owner )
 14  select * from t3;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4120770359

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                             |    37 |  3404 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                             |       |       |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA551_C656D5E3 |       |       |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |                             |    37 |   222 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | T                           | 82667 |   484K|
|   5 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA552_C656D5E3 |       |       |
|   6 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |                             |    37 |   407 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | T                           | 82667 |   888K|
|   8 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA553_C656D5E3 |       |       |
|*  9 |    HASH JOIN                             |                             |    37 |  5846 |
|  10 |     VIEW                                 |                             |    37 |  2923 |
|  11 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA551_C656D5E3 |    37 |   222 |
|  12 |     VIEW                                 |                             |    37 |  2923 |
|  13 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA552_C656D5E3 |    37 |   407 |
|  14 |   VIEW                                   |                             |    37 |  3404 |
|  15 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9DA553_C656D5E3 |    37 |  1184 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   9 - access("T1"."OWNER"="T2"."OWNER")
```